# Split time series by periods of activity

Tags: time-series

I have a collection of time series that involve periods of activity and inactivity.

```
ts = CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/568b5aa9-627c-4d05-bcd6-ed92cce2f1cf"];
First[ts]["Dates"] // DateHistogram
```

[image]

I want to split them into separate series each corresponding to periods of activity. My naive approach seems to work well but is very slow (I have thousands of these series).

```
split[t_] := With[{c = FindClusters @ Normal[t][[All, 1]]},
  Map[TimeSeriesWindow[t, MinMax @ #] &, c]];
First[ts] // split // DateHistogram
```

[image]

Is there a more efficient way to split these? (I am already taking advantage of subkernels.)

Comment: You could specify what constitutes an "activity period" by requiring time between events to be smaller that a given threshold. Investigating time stamps differences might help: `In[10]:= MinMax@Differences[ts[36100]["Dates"]]
Out[10]= {Quantity[1.841, "Seconds"], Quantity[11.9813, "Hours"]}`